# launching my application using the main method

Tags: java

I have used Netbeans to create a swing arm project. How do i use the main method to launch my application?

Comment: yo mean to run it from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            new TutoringWages().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

This should be a method inside your class. For example,

```
package pkg.to.tw;
public class TutoringWages extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new TutoringWages().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    //more code such as constructors, field methods, etc.
    //...
} //finally the end.
```

Netbeans automatically builds a jar for you. In netbeans push clean and build, which will generate a jar file in the dist folder of the project. If you aren't using this great feature, then you can do this:

```
cd src
javac pkg/to/tw/TutoringWages.java
java pkg.to.tw.TutoringWages
```

Then in runs. Do not include the .class extension in the `java` command. It will produce errors.

Comment: Okay, this is what i see for main methods below. Should this be at the very top under class? What is it specifically that i would use to call from the commandline?                                                                                                                                                                                                       public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TutoringWages().setVisible(true);
            }
          }
        );
      }